# How to get the full Hierarchy with SQL CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, recursive-query

Hi I am trying to get the full hierarchy of my category. Here is my sample table

```
ID     PARENT_ID       NAME          DEPTH
------------------------------------------
1      NULL            A             1
2      NULL            B             1
3      NULL            C             1
4      1               D             2
5      4               E             3
```

The cte output should be this

```
ID     PARENT_ID       NAME
---------------------------
1      NULL            A             
2      NULL            B             
3      NULL            C             
4      1               D             
5      4               E             
5      1               E
```

As you can see id:5 is parent of 4 and 1. How do i query the whole tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE(ID INT,ParentID INT,NAME VARCHAR(10),DEPTH INT)

INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES
(1      ,NULL            ,'A'             ,1 ),
(2      ,NULL            ,'B'             ,1 ),
(3      ,NULL            ,'C'             ,1 ),
(4      ,1               ,'D'             ,2 ),
(5      ,4               ,'E'            ,3 ),
(6      ,5               ,'F'            ,4 );

select * from @tmp

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT   A.ID
            ,A.ParentID
            ,A.NAME
            ,A.DEPTH
    FROM    @tmp A

    UNION ALL

    SELECT   A.ID
            ,B.ParentID
            ,A.NAME
            ,A.DEPTH 
    FROM    cte A 
    INNER JOIN @tmp B on A.ParentID = B.ID 
    WHERE   B.ParentID IS NOT NULL

)

SELECT * FROM cte
```

Comment: The query will not work if there are more than one row at the same depth, i.e. if there were three more rows at depth 3 and with parent 4

Comment: Hello, I have posted another question about this topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8517097/184773. Can you check it out for me. I see you are very knowledgable about sql server.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2008 CTE can be use to query recursively.

Example of CTE from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)

-- Sample Solution (Untested)

```
;With TableCTE(Id, Name, ParentId, Depth)
(
   Select ID,Name,ParentId, 1
     FROM MyTable

   Union All

   Select C.Id, C.Name, t.ParentId, c.Depth +1
     FROM @tmp t
    INNER JOIN TableCTE C on t.Id = c.ParentId
    -- Where t.ParentId IS Not Null
)

SELECT Id, Name, ParentId
FROM TableCTE
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not return that id: 5 is a parent of id:1

Comment: CTE loops recursively till it returns any rows, so if you want to loop back we have to tweak a query, please see the updated answer.

Comment: Removed the 'Where t.ParentId IS NOT NULL' clause as it was giving erroneous results i.e. Depth 1 and 2 were all seen as depth 1 and the subsequent depths were 1 less than what they should be

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT   A.ID
            ,A.ParentID
            ,A.NAME
            ,A.DEPTH
    FROM    @tmp A
    WHERE   A.ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT   B.ID
            ,B.ParentID
            ,B.NAME
            ,B.DEPTH 
    FROM    cte A 
              INNER JOIN 
            @tmp B on B.ParentID = A.ID
    WHERE   B.ParentID IS NOT NULL

)

SELECT * FROM cte
```