# How to get the hierarchy level of this query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get the hierarchy level of this query. Here is the CTE recursive query

```
WITH CategoryRec AS 
(
    SELECT Id, Parentid, Name
    FROM dbo.Category

    UNION ALL

    SELECT cr.Id, c.Parentid, cr.Name
    FROM CategoryRec AS cr INNER JOIN dbo.Category AS c ON cr.Parentid = c.Id
    WHERE c.Parentid IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT DISTINCT Id, Parentid, Name
FROM  CategoryRec
```

This question is related to this question here: [How to get the full Hierarchy with SQL CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483879/how-to-get-the-full-hierarchy-with-sql-cte)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a column called `Level` (or whatever you want to call it) - both to the "anchor" SELECT as well as the recursive part of your CTE - like this:

```
WITH CategoryRec AS 
(
    SELECT Id, Parentid, Name, 1 AS 'Level'
    FROM dbo.Category

    UNION ALL

    SELECT cr.Id, c.Parentid, cr.Name, cr.Level + 1 
    FROM CategoryRec AS cr 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Category AS c ON cr.Parentid = c.Id
    WHERE c.Parentid IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT DISTINCT Id, Parentid, Name, Level
FROM  CategoryRec
```

Comment: Actually this one didnt work. It returned the incorrect levels

Comment: I have created a test category hierarchy and the levels where not what I expected. for example, A particular id would show several levels for different parents. No matter what the parent is the level should always stay the same.

Comment: @Luke101: in that case, you have a different definition of "level" than I do .... to me, a level in a hierarchy for a child node is always 1 more than his parent node. If that given node shows up under different parents, I would assume that its level is different - always depending on the parent's level...

Comment: In the previous question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483879/how-to-get-the-full-hierarchy-with-sql-cte. I have referenced that post in this question. That should clear up any misunderstanding. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to select the top level of your hierarchy in the the first query with the level as marc_s wrote.

```
;WITH CategoryRec AS 
(
  SELECT a.Id, 
         a.Parentid, 
         a.Name, 
         1 AS 'Level'
    FROM dbo.Category as a
   WHERE a.Parentid IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT b.Id, 
         b.Parentid, 
         b.Name, 
         a.Level + 1 
    FROM CategoryRec  as a
           INNER JOIN 
         dbo.Category as b on b.Parentid = a.Id
   WHERE b.Parentid IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT Id, Parentid, Name, Level
FROM  CategoryRec
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns the correct levels. But not sure if this query is performant is it should be

```
WITH CategoryRec AS 
(
    SELECT     Id, Parentid, Name, 1 as [Level]
    FROM dbo.Category
    where Parentid IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.Id, c.Parentid, c.Name, (cr.[Level] + 1) as [Level]
    FROM Category c INNER JOIN
    CategoryRec AS cr ON c.Parentid = cr.Id
),
CategoryRec2 as
(
    SELECT Id, Parentid, Name, [Level]
    FROM CategoryRec

    UNION ALL

    SELECT cr.Id, c.Parentid, cr.Name, cr.[Level]
    FROM CategoryRec2 AS cr INNER JOIN
    CategoryRec AS c ON cr.Parentid = c.Id
    WHERE c.Parentid IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT Id, Parentid, Name, [Level]
FROM CategoryRec2
```

Comment: I don't see why you need the CategoryRec2 query. Surely you just need to add the "WHERE c.Parentid IS NOT NULL" clause to the query after the 'UNION ALL' of the CategoryRec query. Then you can drop the CategoryRec2 cte and it should work (?)